# Why is assigning a container's element to the container (not) a well-defined C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, assignment-operator, copy-assignment, memory-aliasing

In C++ there is the infamous problem of self-assignment: when implementing `operator=(const T &other)`, one has to be careful of the `this == &other` case to not destroy `this`'s data before copying it from `other`.

However, `*this` and `other` may interact in more interesting ways than being the same object. Namely, one may contain the other.  Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
struct Foo {
    std::string s = "hello world very long string";
    std::vector<Foo> children;
};
int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> f(4);
    f[0].children.resize(2);
    f = f[0].children;  // (1)
    // auto tmp = f[0].children; f = std::move(tmp);  // (2)
    std::cout << f.size() << "\n";
}
```

I'd expect that lines `(1)` and `(2)` are identical: program is well-defined to print `2`.  However, I'm yet to find a compiler+standard library combination that works with line `(1)` and Address Sanitizer enabled: [GCC+stdlibc++, Clang+libc++](https://godbolt.org/z/1bshesqYW) and Visual Studio+Microsoft STL all crash.

Curiously, disabling Address Sanitizer removes the crash and the program starts printing `2`.

Why is this operation prohibited or permitted in the standard C++?

Extra question: same, but with `f[0].children = f`. Extra-extra question: use `std::any` instead of `std::vector<Foo>`.

Comment: For practical purposes (I know it is a language lawyer question, but this is a comment, not an answer), one could A) in some cases (e.g. if the change in (1) is only in local variables) use a plain pointer `std::vector<Foo>*` for the type of `f`. Or B) create a custom class for `vector<Foo>`, where the *assignment operator* either B1) takes a value parameter, or B2) does the double-move of the argument through a temporary variable, or B3) delays the reset of `*this` and with it also delays the destruction of the contained elements, e.g. by using the swap idiom.

Comment: One probably would have to change/override (together with the *assignment operator*) all operations, which could lead to a resize before copying (e.g. `push_back`) as they could make the reference parameter invalid, too, before the copying commences.

Comment: 1 and 2 would be equivalent in case copy-swap or similar idiom were utilized, in its current form 2 makes one intermediate copy that actually saves the day. Add printout to destructor https://godbolt.org/z/PM98e4Y53 and you'll see that with asan off theres is a clear memory corruption.

Comment: Arthur O'Dwyer talked about this problem at CppCon 2019. He was writing a copy-assignment `operator=`, and used an example that is similar to yours. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ&t=849s) takes you to the middle of his talk, where he discusses the assignment `v = v[1];` He provides the example as motivation for using the _copy and swap_ idiom in his copy-assignment operator, noting the the usual checks against self-assignment cannot protect you from destroying v (and v[1] along with it), _before_ copying the elements of v[1] into v.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not convinced that (1) is well-defined, because in order to copy a new value into `f[0]`, the old object residing at that location must first be destroyed, or is at the very least modified while under the contract of being *const*.

From [std::vector<T,Allocator>::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) (*emphasis mine*):

> If the allocator of `*this` after assignment would compare unequal to its old value, the old allocator is used to deallocate the memory, then the new allocator is used to allocate it before copying the elements. Otherwise, the memory owned by `*this` *may be reused* when possible. In any case, the elements originally belonging to `*this` *may be either destroyed or replaced* by element-wise copy-assignment.

So it would be expected that in all scenarios above, it's possible the object is destroyed before it's be copied, and you fall into the territory of behavior that is either undefined or specific to an implementation.

In practical terms, for the vector to re-use this memory it generally necessitates *placement-delete* followed by *placement-new* and in these cases once again the referenced object being copied is destroyed in the process.

Even in the most lenient scenario (*i.e.* *"replaced by element-wise copy-assignment"*) you begin with `Foo::operator=(const Foo&)` invoked on `f[0]` to replace it with a copy of `f[0].children[0]`. The vector `f[0].children[0].children` is empty, and so the copy will result in both elements of `f[0].children` being destroyed but leaving the target vector's capacity (which is 2) unchanged. Before even getting to the next element, the `const Foo&` that was originally being copied has been modified, breaking its contract and all bets are off.

I don't think there's any automatic way to protect against that without maybe using some kind of custom garbage-collecting allocator. You simply need to recognize the self-referential problem and avoid it. You worked around the problem in (2) by introducing a copy, and *that* is at least well-defined. It can be taken one step further by moving the data out of the container first:

```
auto tmp = std::move(f[0].children);
f = std::move(tmp);
```

Perhaps the problem can be more generally worked around with careful application of `std::shared_ptr`, since your main issue is the destruction of data that you expected is still referenced.

I think the whole contract-breaking-of-const-object stuff is really the key to answering your "extra" question about `f[0].children = f` without getting too deep in details. In this case, `children` may be reallocated due to the required increase in capacity, and in doing so modifies `f` which was supposed to be const.

Comment: *"while under the contract of being const"* Passing an object as an argument for a `const` reference parameter doesn't create such a contract. The `const` only requires that the function doesn't use that reference to modify the referred object. Maybe the function also requires the argument to be unchanged, in which case the answer should provide a reference to that requirement.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux please define "unchanged", e.g. add "mutable" into the equation ;)